# Verify user and password against a file created by htpasswd

Tags: apache, .htpasswd

Is there a way, from the command line, to check a user and password against a file created by htpasswd, the tool provided by Apache?

Comment: Hmm.  There's a [tag:htpasswd] tag for questions about the `htpasswd` program, but the system won't let it coexist with the [tag:.htpasswd] tag...

Comment: You still haven't accepted the answer. Shame on you.

Answer (score 52):

You can use the `htpasswd` tool for this.

```
# create htpasswd_file with user:password
$ htpasswd -cb htpasswd_file user password
Adding password for user user

# verify password for user
$ htpasswd -vb htpasswd_file user wrongpassword
password verification failed

$ htpasswd -vb htpasswd_file user password
Password for user user correct.
```

Exit status is `0` for success, `3` for failure.

Comment: It's generally more secure to omit `-b` and type the password into a prompt. Using the above command, the plaintext password may end up in your `.bash_history`.

Answer (score 42):

Assuming you create the password using the following command and "myPassword" as the password

```
htpasswd -c /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords username
```

This will create a file that looks like

```
username:$apr1$sr15veBe$cwxJZHTVLHBkZKUoTHV.k.
```

The $apr1$ is the hashing method, sr15veBe is the salt, and the last string is the hashed password. You can validate it using openssl using

```
openssl passwd -apr1 -salt sr15veBe myPassword
```

which will output

```
$apr1$sr15veBe$cwxJZHTVLHBkZKUoTHV.k.
```

A pipeline which you could use would be:

```
username="something"
htpasswd -c /usr/local/apache/passwd/passwords $username
****Enter password:****

salt=$($(cat passwords | cut -d$ -f3)
password=$(openssl passwd -apr1 -salt $salt)
****Enter password:****

grep -q $username:$password passwords 
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
 then echo "password is valid"
else 
 echo "password is invalid"
fi
```

You may need to change your openssl command, as Apache's htpasswd command crypts slightly differently on each system.

For more information, visit Apache's page on the topic at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/misc/password_encryptions.html