# How to stop ldapsearch(1) from base64 encoding userPassword and other attributes?

Tags: bash, ldap

The `ldapsearch(1)` command retrieves objects from an LDAP server, and prints them out as an LDIF structure, like this (not real data):

```
dn: mail=foo@domain.com,dc=domain,dc=com
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
mail: foo@domain.com
userPassword:: hdfy74dhn79wdhyr74hy7489fhw46789f
```

If an attribute contains non-ASCII data, it is Base64-encoded, indicated by a double `::` after the attribute name.  In addition, it appears that any attribute called `userPassword` will *always* be so encoded, even if it is ASCII-clean.

What I want to do is to tell `ldapsearch` not to do this.  I have not been able to find an option flag to pass to suppress this behaviour; only recompiling the source with `LDAP_PASSWD_DEBUG` disabled.

Is there an undocumented option to prevent this encoding?

(Leaving aside security concerns etc. as this is for testing purposes)

Comment: Did you find another tool which you can trim to not do line breaks (especially not in the middle of a word!) and base64 encoding?

Comment: @RobertSiemer No, the standard tools (by design) do this unless compiled in debug mode (see above).  I've resorted to using the perl alias below.

Comment: @RobertSiemer You can prevent line breaks with the standard option `-o ldap_wrap=no` (which I've just discovered on a Mac needs to be `-o ldap-wrap=no` :(

Comment: @jmb Yeah, I found that out, too. It requieres a recent version, though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short of recompiling ldapsearch, there seems to be no way to do this with a simple flag.

However you can create a shell alias like this, which will have the same effect - provided you have the Perl MIME::Base64 module installed.

```
myldapsearch()
{
ldapsearch "$@" | perl -MMIME::Base64 -n -00 -e 's/\n +//g;s/(?<=:: )(\S+)/decode_base64($1)/eg;print'
}
alias ldapsearch=myldapsearch
```

Comment: I found in this book http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=963814 a slightly different variation defining a charset :
`perl -MMIME::Base64 -MEncode=decode -n -00 -e 's/\n +//g;s/(?<=:: )(\S+)/decode("UTF-8",decode_base64($1))/eg;print'`

Comment: You may want to add `binmode STDOUT, ':utf8'` to that oneliner; otherwise, perl will complain of wide characters in the input and output stuff in a single-byte encoding.

Comment: Indeed, only base64-encoded values are shown with the double-colon attribute prefix, https://git.openldap.org/openldap/openldap/-/blob/788e959/clients/tools/common.c#L2263

Comment: @eelghEEz The double colon syntax for base64 encoded values is part of the LDIF standard (RFC2849).

Comment: You may also want to replace that `::` with a `:`, seeing as the output is no longer encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Don't want to open old topics but maybe it could help someone with what I found out. In my case I got a base64 encoded string from the LDAP Search in a case where I had a space at the end of the line, which wasn't directly visible for me. Maybe that isn't the case for you @steve-shipway but it was for me.