# Ldapsearch and base64 encoding of non ASCII values

Tags: ldap, base64

If the database contains non ASCII data like (Lehtelä) , the Ldapsearch returns it as an base64 encoded (:: TGVodGVsw6Q=) .
I followed this blog, for decoding it(https://lurchi.wordpress.com/2009/11/03/ldapsearch-and-base64-encoding/)

It only helps if the base64 is a single line value, how to handle it if value spans across multiple lines.

```
 ldapsearch -x -H ldap://76.656.23.56 -D cn=admin -w abc -b "o=my_comp" -s sub -LLL 'mail=mail@gmail.com'  sn nrfAssignedResources | un64

dn: cn=SBOSTRO2,ou=Employees,ou=Active,ou=Identities,ou=Meta,o=VCC
base64: invalid input
nrfAssignedResources:: "cn=VCCBIZ GPO 0100 account,cn=ResourceDef"
 zLGNuPVJvbGVDb25maWcsY249QXBwQ29uZmlnLGNuPVVBLGNuPURyaXZlclNldCxvdT1TeXN0ZW0s
 bz1WQ0MjMiM8YXNzaWdubWsjdfahgsgacgfacxfg sahhagsvgcagjMyMzZaPC9zdGFydF90bT48c
 mVxX3RtPjIwMTQwMTI3MDYzMjM2WjwvcmVxX3RtPjxpbnN0LWd1aWQ+ZGM5M2ZkODRjYmQ3NGY3MG
 JjM2VmZjRlODAyZDdlMjE8L2luc3QtZ3VpZD48cmVxPmNuPUpBU1BMVU5ELG91PUVtcGxveWVlcyx
 W50Pg==
sn:: "Boström "
```

As you can see here, because **sn** has only single  line its complete("Boström") and **nrfAssignedResources** value is multiple line, only first line is decoded not the rest.
the AWK code is available in the link above.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please do re-phrase it, along with that do add samples of input and expected output too, with your efforts.

Comment: Why would it span over multiple lines? Can you give an example input which you would like to see decoded?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38710484 with a Perl one-liner for the de-unicoding step, which works (unlike the awk three-liner in the cited blog post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your ldapsearch the option `-o ldif-wrap=no` which should avoid the wrapping.

Comment: This doesn't actually fix base64 encoding from what I can tell.